# Kotlin Изменить програмно цвет CardView по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: android, kotlin

Мне нужно по нажатию на кнопку изменить cardBackgroundColor в файле note_rv_item_1.xml в коде моего основного activity. Как я могу это сделать и могу ли вообще?

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainRL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/theme2"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/notesRV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="618dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        tools:listitem="@layout/note_rv_item_1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

note_rv_item_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTVNote"
            android:layout_width="381dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/idIVDelete"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/idIVStar"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="11dp"
            android:text="Note"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/idIVDelete"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/delete" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/idIVStar"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="350dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:button="@drawable/check_box"
            android:buttonTint="@color/white"
            android:padding="3dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Вот сюда мне нужно вписать изменение параметра в моём MainActivity.kt, но я не знаю как это сделать и решения в интернете не нашёл.

```
themeBtn.setOnClickListener {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val color = ContextCompact.getColor(context, R.color.red)
card.setCardBackgroundColor(color)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Это не работает для меня. Может что-то дополнительное нужно добавить, подскажите пожалуйста, я просто новичок в этом. У меня ругается на context и ContextCompact